# How to start emulator from ADT plugin with proxy host/port/user/password?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm realizing that one problem I had with an app in the emulator is because the emulator wasn't working with my proxy.  I have to set a proxy host, port, user, and password.  I don't see any options for setting this from the ADT.  I noticed that if you run the emulator from the command line, there is a "-http-proxy" option, but that's not available from the AVD Manager that is started from Eclipse.  I also noticed that when I run the "SDK Manager" outside of Eclipse, there is an additional settings section labeled "Settings" which has proxy settings, but that's only the host and port, not user and password.

Did no one realize that some people would be running this from behind an authenticated proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting them in the mobile networks for the emulator by editing the API. If that doesnt work try something called as proxifier...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Please elaborate.

Comment: There is application called Proxifier. Install the application, add your proxy details in the Proxy tab called "Proxy Settings" once done, start the ANDROID emulator. It should make connections through the "Proxifier" using the user/pass added to make a connection. Works for me atleast.

Comment: About the api settings, it only allows the use of browser not the application network connection. And i hope that u just want this for the android emulator and not on device.

Answer (score 0):

Within Eclipse, you can set it by going to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Proxy Entries. Select and edit HTTP/HTTPS as needed.

Comment: Did you think I would be using Eclipse within an authenticated proxy without already having that set in the "Network Connections" section?  I set that a long time ago.  I wouldn't be able to install and update plugins without it. The AVD doesn't use those settings.

Comment: Alright. If you are running on Windows, can you try adding -Dhttp.proxyUsername="user" -Dhttp.proxyPassword="password" to your android.bat file?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to Run->Run Configurations.  Select your application and then click on the "Target" tab.  In the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" you can type in the -http-proxy argument and any other arbitrary command line options you need.  You might need to restart the emulator and/or your computer for the changes to take effect.

You could also just start the emulator from the command line, with the proxy switch.  Eclipse will still deploy your application to it.  It really won't make a difference during your development process.

The final thing to try is to set the proxy inside the emulator.  If you drill into the APN settings on the device (something like settings->wireless and networks->) there are proxy settings.  These will persist on the emulator.  You might need to restart the emulator without the proxy switch after setting these.

Hopefully, one of these will work for you.  Overall, I've found proxy support in the emulator to be pretty flaky.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a "right" way to do this, but if all else fails, you could find an open source non-authenticated proxy, and run a local copy that you've modified to authenticate to the real (remote) proxy that it forwards everything through.  Then you'd only have to tell the emulator about a vanilla unauthenticated proxy.

Or if even that won't work, you could hack your machine's network stack to push everything through the proxy and automatically handle the authentication.

But there's probably a better way.